# SSIS column name copy from mapping window

Tags: ssis

I need help on copying the column names from the mapping window of SSIS OLEDB Editor.Currently I am noting down manually.[image: mapping window of SSIS OLEDB editor]

Comment: I doubt if there is any special tool by which you can copy the mapping details .BTW why do u need to copy the details ? r u using it somewhere in SSIS?

Comment: @praveen I need to create mapping documents for already existing SSIS mappings.Its taking a lot of time to manually look and keep typing and chances of errors are more.so thought of any way of automising it.Thanks for your comment.If by chance you get anything then please let me know...

Comment: SSIS package is XML based, you can try to right click package open with notepad editor and try to find tags for these mappings and copy text and format it.

Comment: @rs : thanks a lot..it works and addresses my issue..thanks a lot again and it has reduced a bulk of my work indeed.

Comment: rs, you should cut this out and post it as an answer :-)

Comment: @satyajit i posted my comment as answer, please accept that if my answer helped you fix your issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SSIS` package is `XML` based, you can try to right click package open with notepad editor and try to find tags for these mappings and copy text and format it.

Comment: Not to rain on your parade, but have you actually tried this? The XML, pre SQL Server 2012, is going to be a nearly unnavigable mess. `<inputColumn id="1332" name="" description="" lineageId="1241" usageType="readOnly" errorOrTruncationOperation="" errorRowDisposition="NotUsed" truncationRowDisposition="NotUsed" externalMetadataColumnId="1291" mappedColumnId="0"/>`Now all they need to do is find where the various IDs are defined and then grab the associated names. Accounting of course for asynchronous components which will change lineage ids...

Comment: @billinkc, yes i did, i used xml before to find info and for same reason i posted this answer. And also check OP comment above he was able to get info he wanted from xml

Answer (score 2):

If you are doing this to try to document your SSIS package, you should try a third party documentation app.  One example of this is [BI-Documenter](http://pragmaticworks.com/Products/BI-Documenter/TrialDownload.aspx) from Pragmatic Works.